# Multiple line matrix equations

Tags: line-breaking, align, matrices

I am trying to fit a rather large matrix equation into a document, but it is so large that I cannot fit it onto a single line.
Moving the end of the equation onto a new line appears to be the only way to fit everything on. 
The matrix is in a series of array elements, and when trying to separate the last matrix, but no matter what I try it doesn't seem to be placed onto a new line.
Most recently I have been trying split it using the align or multline, but trying to newline the text isn't working.

```
\centerline{
\begin{minipage}[h!]{0.85\paperwidth}
\begin{align*}
\begin{scriptsize}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right)\newline
+\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right)
\end{scriptsize}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}}
```

Comment: `\centerline` isn't really a latex command (it is just a left over from plain) `\begin{minipage}[h!]` does not take `h` or `!` in its argument you can't use `\begin{scriptsize}` in `align`

Answer (score 1):

It was a bit hard to guess the intended layout from the markup fragment shown. It does not seem very wide unless you are setting in narrow columns. I set what I think was the intended expression on one line or two:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}


\begin{multline*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\
{}+
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```